# How do I apply a ast.NodeTransformer to imports?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I'd like to a apply a NodeTransformer not just to the current file's AST, but to any code imported as well. If you run the below code, you will note that the transformer works, but only for the single file read and parsed. How would I modify this code to apply the transformer to any imports in the parsed code?

a.py:

```
from b import q


def r(a):
    return q(a) + 5
```

b.py:

```
def q(n):
    return r(n + 1)


def r(n):
    return n
```

Main.py:

```
import ast
import astor


class trivial_transformer(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
        body = []
        for line in node.body:
            body.append(
                ast.Expr(
                    ast.Call(func=ast.Name('print', ctx=ast.Load()),
                             args=[ast.Str(s="Doing: "+astor.to_source(line).strip())],
                             keywords=[])))
            body.append(self.generic_visit(line))
        node.body = body
        return node


parsed_ast = ast.fix_missing_locations(trivial_transformer().visit(ast.parse(open('a.py','r').read())))
g = {}
eval(compile(parsed_ast, '<source>', 'exec'), g)
print(g['r'](5))
```

This yields:

```
Doing: return q(a) + 5
11
```

But I'd like it to yield:

```
Doing: return q(a) + 5
Doing: return r(n + 1)
Doing: return n
11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it took some doing, but I got it (woo):

```
import ast
import astor
import importlib
import sys

class trivial_transformer(ast.NodeTransformer):

    def processImport(self, imp):
        if imp not in sys.modules:
            spec = importlib.util.find_spec(imp)
            helper = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
            parsed_dep = ast.fix_missing_locations(self.visit(ast.parse(spec.loader.get_source(imp))))
            exec(compile(parsed_dep, imp, 'exec'), helper.__dict__)
            sys.modules[imp] = helper

    def visit_ImportFrom(self, node):
        self.processImport(node.module)
        return node

    def visit_Import(self, node):
        for i in node.names:
            self.processImport(i.name)
        return node

    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
        body = []
        for line in node.body:
            body.append(
                ast.Expr(
                    ast.Call(func=ast.Name('print', ctx=ast.Load()),
                             args=[ast.Str(s="Doing: "+astor.to_source(line).strip())],
                             keywords=[])))
            body.append(self.generic_visit(line))
        node.body = body
        return node


init = 'a'
trivial_transformer().processImport(init)

import a
a.r(5)
```